# PDOException "could not find driver" on MAMP

Tags: php, pdo, mamp

I'm trying to work with PDO on my localhost. I'm running MAMP on OSX 10.7.4.

I've checked phpinfo(), and as far as I can see I should be fine.

[image]

I checked the php.ini to see that "extension=pdo_mysql.so" is in fact uncommented.

I read some were that I had to make the file PROJECTFOLDER/config/parameters.ini with the following content so i did, but with no luck. (Changed it to reflect my setup of cause)

```
database_driver   = pdo_mysql
database_host     = localhost
database_port     =
database_name     = databasename
database_user     = msqlusername
database_password = mysqlpassword//if not make blank

mailer_transport  = smtp
mailer_host       = localhost
mailer_user       =
mailer_password   =

locale            = en

secret            = ThisTokenIsNotSoSecretChangeIt
```

**Any ideas as to how I can get PDO up and running?**

BTW I'm using the following code to make the connection:

```
try {  
    $host = 'localhost';
    $dbname = 'ifjernsyn';
    $user = 'root';
    $pass = 'root';

    # MS SQL Server and Sybase with PDO_DBLIB  
    $DBH = new PDO("mssql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname, $user, $pass");  
    $DBH = new PDO("sybase:host=$host;dbname=$dbname, $user, $pass");  

    # MySQL with PDO_MYSQL  
    $DBH = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname", $user, $pass);  

    # SQLite Database  
    $DBH = new PDO("sqlite:my/database/path/database.db");  
}  
catch(PDOException $e) {  
    echo $e->getMessage();  
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So there is not `mssql` and `sybase` 's driver.

You need [PDO_DBLIB](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-dblib.php) to  access Microsoft SQL Server and Sybase databases.

Comment: Either I havn't succesfully installed it or this is not the answer.

I donwloaded it at http://www.ziqijin.com/?p=60 ran chmod +x on it and placed it in /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.3.6/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626. I then went to file->edit template->php->php 5.3.6 php.ini in MAMP Pro and made a new line with extension=pdo_dblib.so after the other extension declarations. I then restarted MAMP, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: I'm not sure if it's possible to un-accept an answer, but that might be your best bet at getting this question answered, or maybe re-ask it? I'm having the same problem with the latest MAMP.